# Change values of Bundle parameters of addPeriodicSync()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-syncadapter, android-background, android-bundle

I am using a `SyncAdapter` in my application in which the frequency of Periodic Sync is increased when user enters a particular activity.

I wanted to know if there is a way in which I can let the application know which activity has called the `SyncAdapter`?

I tried setting a public static boolean variable to true when it enters the fast frequency Activity but the `SyncAdapter` method `onPerformSync()` always prints false. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `extras` that are passed to your `SyncAdapter` to transport more information about the "trigger" of a sync action.

That your static variable is not properly set when questioned from the `SyncAdapter` could mean that you execute your sync service in a separate process than the rest of your app. This is usually done by specifying the `android:process="..."` attribute in the `<service>` definition.